# Can't boot from USB "Secure boot not enabled"

Tags: live-usb, uefi

I followed how to [Create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) for creating a USB install with persistence.

but when I try to boot from USB, I get this 1 line message "Secure boot not enabled". It's white text on a black screen, and then nothing else happens and I have to restart.

Indeed, I have disabled secure mode in UEFI (so I can boot off an Ubuntu partition on my HD). I'm not interested in turning secure boot back on, as it leads to all sorts of other complications with my other boot partitions. I've tried my USB 3.0 and USB 2.0 ports. I don't see any fast boot options in UEFI. I have an Acer Aspire v3 551. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have windows 8 installed?

Comment: Yes, Windows 8 Professional

Comment: "Secure boot not enabled" is *not* an error message; it's just a notification of the fact (that you already knew) that Secure Boot is not enabled. You don't say what happens *after* that message, so it's not clear what the problem is. You refer to "all the same errors" when Secure Boot is enabled, but you don't say what those errors are, or when else they occur. In sum, your question provides inadequate information to even begin to guess at a solution.

Comment: Sorry Rod, hope my edits clarify

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: I never did fully figure this out. Eventually I think I started over and used MBR partitions and got it working using BIOS instead of UEFI